# Changing value of string in one of the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change value of string element by click in another element. This actually works but in very simple version:

```
$('.plus').click(function(){

var num = $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text()) + 1);
$(this).next().text(num);

});
```

Now i wanna make this code works in Ajax connection. I Don't know how to get access to this particular element (next doesnt work in this scenario).

```
$('.plus').click(function(){

        var idpod = $(this).next().data('value');
        var ipuser = $('#ipuser').text();


          $.ajax({
            url: './inc/zapis_punktow.php',
            data: {'idpod': idpod, 'ipuser': ipuser},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(odp){

                if(odp == 1){

                    alert ('Plus na to podobieństwo został już dodany!');

                }else{

//THERE IS THE PLACE THAT CHANGING VALUE SHOULD CHANGE

                    var num = $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text()) + 1);
                    $(this).next().text(num);

                }           

            }

           });


});
```

How i can change value of this same element like in simple scenario but in 2nd version? i want to change the value only the element which is next to plus click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do :

```
$('.plus').click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var idpod = $(this).next().data('value');
    var ipuser = $('#ipuser').text();


      $.ajax({
        url: './inc/zapis_punktow.php',
        data: {'idpod': idpod, 'ipuser': ipuser},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(odp){

            if(odp == 1){

                alert ('Plus na to podobieństwo został już dodany!');

            }else{

            //THERE IS THE PLACE THAT CHANGING VALUE SHOULD CHANGE

                var num = self.next().text(parseInt(self.next().text()) + 1);
                self.next().text(num);

            }           

        }

       });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to move out the `var num` up outside of ajax:

```
$('.plus').click(function(){

    var idpod = $(this).next().data('value');
    var ipuser = $('#ipuser').text();
    var num = $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text()) + 1);
```

So your else part should look like this:

```
}else{
//THERE IS THE PLACE THAT CHANGING VALUE SHOULD CHANGE
    $(this).next().text(num);
}
```